# How to load data from text file into a single column using SSIS

Tags: ssis-2012

I have a text file with huge data and the data are comma separated. I am trying to load the data into a single column and then perform some string functions using derived column to get the data that is needed and save it to a CSV file. The data has lot of noise. Whenever I am  loading the data into a single column and trying to use string operations it shows me an error saying the data is in **`DT_TEXT`** format. I am trying to typecast it into **`DT_String`** but no luck so far.

I am guessing maybe I am loading the text file in a wrong way. Whenever I am loading it into a single column I am facing this problem.

Any leads would be of much help!

The data in the text file looks like this.

```
{"ts":"2016-08-01T13:28:14.136","pid":2480,"tid":"2db4","sev":"info","req":"-","sess":"-","site":"-","user":"-","k":"rotate-log",
"v":{"new-path":"E:\\Tableau\\Tableau Server2\\data\\tabsvc\\vizqlserver\\Logs\\dataserver_0_2016_08_01_13_28_14.txt","old-path":"E:\\Tableau\\Tableau Server2\\data\\tabsvc\\vizqlserver\\Logs\\dataserver_0_2016_07_31_13_27_15.txt"}}
{"ts":"2016-08-01T13:28:14.120","pid":2480,"tid":"24c4","sev":"info","req":"-","sess":"-","site":"-","user":"-","k":"msg","v":"ACTION: DataSession::ReportException"}
{"ts":"2016-08-01T13:28:14.120","pid":2480,"tid":"24c4","sev":"warn","req":"-","sess":"-","site":"-","user":"-","k":"msg","v":"NotifyOfException::std::exception"}
{"ts":"2016-08-01T13:28:14.120","pid":2480,"tid":"24c4","sev":"warn","req":"-","sess":"-","site":"-","user":"-","k":"msg","v":"NotifyOfException caught std::exception."}
{"ts":"2016-08-01T13:28:14.183","pid":2480,"tid":"24c4","sev":"info","req":"-","sess":"-","site":"-","user":"-","k":"msg","v":"ACTION: DataSession::ReportException"}
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: when type casting it are you setting a length long enough to handle the conversion?  Also while that data is certainly messy to deal with you can still harness the power of the flat file connection and break it to multiple columns based on comma delimited and what I assume is CRLF for the row delimiter.  Doing so will allow you to deal with smaller pieces of the whole string to more easily get to what you want.  In that flat file connection manager you can also specify the string to be DT_String instead of DT_Text but make sure you have a long enough max length

Comment: Yes, i specified the string to be DT_String . But I didn't specify the length to be long enough and that's why it was throwing an error. I checked and now it working fine.  Thanks much !